# Submitting the form after receiving ajax response

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jquery, websphere-commerce

I have a scenario where I need to use ajax to invoke the controller command. After the command is successfully executed, it returns me a ViewName.
But this view is not getting invoked (JSP page corresponding to this view is not loaded). But I am getting the ajax response back.

I want to make the ajax call. And when I receive the response, based on this I want to submit the form. And the ajax response should be available for me on this JSP page that gets loaded.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: loads of ways to do it. what did you try?

Comment: Could you please suggest me one way

Comment: is this an out of the box command, what command, what view?

Answer (score 0):

One option: put a hidden field into your form. Once the ajax call comes back, in your success function, you put your response data into the hidden field. Based on any other parameter your might set the action of the form. Finally submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the ajax call is to return data back to the existing page, but if the json is returning a view name, just set the window location to the viewname in javascript.  That will forward the browser to the appropriate place.